# connecting to PostgreSQL from OSGi application deployed in Karaf container

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, osgi, karaf

I'm using Hibernate to connect to PostgreSQL from a Karaf 2.3.4 container, when i deploy my bundle there is an exception saying javax.naming.NameNotFoundException osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/"(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresds).

Here is my persistance.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="HibernateOSGi_ContainerManaged"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresds)</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.hibernate.osgitest.entity.DataPoint</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my blueprint.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<blueprint default-activation="eager"
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0" xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="dpService" class="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointServiceImpl">
        <jpa:context unitname="HibernateOSGi_ContainerManaged" property="entityManager" />
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
    </bean>

    <service ref="dpService" interface="org.hibernate.osgitest.DataPointService" />

    <command-bundle xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.1.0">
        <command name="dp/add">
            <action class="org.hibernate.osgitest.command.AddCommand">
                <property name="dpService" ref="dpService" />
            </action>
        </command>
        <command name="dp/getAll">
            <action class="org.hibernate.osgitest.command.GetAllCommand">
                <property name="dpService" ref="dpService" />
            </action>
        </command>
        <command name="dp/deleteAll">
            <action class="org.hibernate.osgitest.command.DeleteAllCommand">
                <property name="dpService" ref="dpService" />
            </action>
        </command>
    </command-bundle>
</blueprint>
```

And here is my datasource-postgres.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

Install the driver in Karaf. As it is no bundle we use the wrap protocol to create a suitable Manifest on the fly:
> install -s wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4

As a last step copy this file to the deploy folder
-->
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="159357123" />
        <property name="dataSourceName" value="postgresds" />
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/postgresds" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

And here is my features.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features>
    <feature name="hibernate-test">

        <feature>karaf-framework</feature>

        <!-- JTA -->
        <config name="org.apache.aries.transaction">
            aries.transaction.recoverable = true
            aries.transaction.timeout = 600
            aries.transaction.howl.logFileDir =
            ${karaf.data}/txlog
            aries.transaction.howl.maxLogFiles = 2
            aries.transaction.howl.maxBlocksPerFile = 512
            aries.transaction.howl.bufferSizeKBytes = 4
        </config>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.manager/1.0.1
        </bundle>

        <!-- JPA -->
        <!-- <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle> -->
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.1
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.api/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint.aries/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context/1.0.1
        </bundle>

        <!-- JNDI -->
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.api/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.core/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.rmi/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.url/1.0.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.aries.jndi/org.apache.aries.jndi.legacy.support/1.0.0
        </bundle>

        <feature>jdbc</feature>
        <!-- Taken from Karaf-Tutorial -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate.common/com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations.common/4.1.0.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:net.sourceforge.serp/serp/1.13.1</bundle>


        <!-- These do not natively support OSGi, so using 3rd party bundles. -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.antlr/2.7.7_5
        </bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.javassist/com.springsource.javassist/3.15.0.GA
        </bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr303-api-1.0.0/2.2.0
        </bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ant/1.8.2_2
        </bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j/1.6.1_5
        </bundle>

        <bundle>wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4</bundle>
        <!--<bundle>mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18</bundle>-->
        <bundle>blueprint:file:C:/Users/yahya/Desktop/Examples/Nouveau/HibernateOSGi-master/datasource-postgres.xml
        </bundle>

        <!-- These do not natively support OSGi, so wrap with BND. -->
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Alpha1</bundle>

        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.1.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml/classmate/0.5.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.0.GA</bundle>

        <!-- JACC is optional. -->
        <!--<bundle>mvn:javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1</bundle> <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc/jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec/1.0.2.Final</bundle> -->

        <!-- hibernate-validator is optional. -->
        <!--<bundle>wrap:mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA</bundle> 
            <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final</bundle> -->

        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.2.Final</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.2.2.Final</bundle>


        <!-- TODO: It seems that the persistence unit bundle needs to be started 
            before hibernate-osgi. When the BundleActivator is started, the persistence 
            unit is provided even though HibernateOSGi_ContainerManaged hasn't completely 
            started yet. If that happens, you'll get an "illegal bundle state" exception. 
            Is there a way for the activator to watch for bundles with PUs before registering 
            the persistence provider? -->
        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/HibernateOSGi_ContainerManaged/1.0.0
        </bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/4.2.2.Final</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

The full stacktrace is:

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/"(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresds)"
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:113)[72:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.url.ServiceRegistryContext.lookup(ServiceRegistryContext.java:144)[72:org.apache.aries.jndi.url:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)[70:org.apache.aries.jndi.core:1.0.0]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.JndiDataSource.getDs(JndiDataSource.java:65)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.unit.impl.DelayedLookupDataSource.getConnection(DelayedLookupDataSource.java:36)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)[91:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)[90:org.hibernate.core:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)[91:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)[91:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:99)[96:org.hibernate.osgi:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.createEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:329)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.registerEntityManagerFactories(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:242)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerFactoryManager.bundleStateChange(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:185)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleManager.setupManager(PersistenceBundleManager.java:394)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceBundleManager.addingService(PersistenceBundleManager.java:209)[67:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:1.0.0]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)[karaf.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)[karaf.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:894)[karaf.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:932)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:793)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:320)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.HibernateBundleActivator.start(HibernateBundleActivator.java:80)[96:org.hibernate.osgi:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:488)[25:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:405)[25:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:401)[25:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.command.InstallFeatureCommand.doExecute(InstallFeatureCommand.java:62)[27:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.command.FeaturesCommandSupport.doExecute(FeaturesCommandSupport.java:41)[27:org.apache.karaf.features.command:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:183)[14:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_51]

I resolved this problem and I updated the list of files as said M. Cristian  but the is a an other strange problem : when restarting Karaf and trying to insert data through Karaf console the console print: The is no active Transaction, so I tried the other way using EntityManager and the problem doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: How can I check the datasource url (full url which connects to the db) through karaf console? Is any command available for that ? I have used command confi:list | grep datasource but it is only giving the name of the datasource and path of the configuation file not the actual url on which datasource is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can not work as the DataSource is published in the same blueprint context where a persistence unit is used.

The problem is that blueprint will wait for an EnitityManagerFactory service to inject. So the DataSource will never be published. Aries JPA will detect that it should create an EntityManagerFactory for your bundle but will timeout trying to find the DataSource.

So put the DataSource into a spearate bundle and it should work.

Comment: Thank you M. Christian Schneider, I resolved the problem using your tutorials and I will update my post

Comment: when restarting Karaf and trying to insert data through Karaf console the console print: Theere is no active Transaction and when trying to get data from database it works !, so I tried the other way using EntityManager and the problem doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: There is no active transaction means that you tried to change data in the db outside of a transaction. This happens if you do not configure container managed transactions (tx:transaction). What did you change in the end to make it work? Extracting the data source into a separate bundle?

Comment: Yes I extracted the datasource into a separate bundle and reordered the install of dependencies in the features.xml file. Thank you a lot Mr Cristian

Comment: How can I check the datasource url (full url which connects to the db) through karaf console? Is any command available for that ? I have used command confi:list | grep datasource but it is only giving the name of the datasource and path of the configuation file not the actual url on which datasource is connected

Comment: Karaf has the jdbc commands (feature:install jdbc). You can not see the url in all cases but you can connect to the DataSource and execute actual queries.